# How to construct a solution given $100$ linearly independent solutions for $T(x)$? An infinite number of solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How will you construct a solution for a homogeneous and ordinary differential equation for $T(x)$ if there are $100$ linearly independent solutions for $T(x)$?  If there are infinite linearly dependent solutions of $T(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean you have a linear combination of 100 functions, and you want an ODE they satisfy? It may not be possible, and clearly you will have to tell us a bit more about your linearly independant components.

Comment: The question is rather vague.  They're asking for a general way to find an ODE if you have 100 linearly independent solutions.  Then the same question if you have an infinite number of solutions.  They're not really looking for an exact equation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(x)$ and $y_1(x)$ be sufficiently differentiable functions and:

$$W(y,y_1) = 
\left| \begin{array}{cc}
y(x) & y_1(x) \\
y'(x) & y'_1(x)
\end{array}
\right| = y y_1' - y_1 y' = 0. \tag{1}
$$

Then the solution of the ODE given by eq. $(1)$ is $y = A\,y_1$ (prove it), where $A$ is a constant of integration. This determinant is known as [***wronskian***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). What will happen for $W(T(x),T_1,T_2, \ldots, T_{100})$?

Hope this is what you are looking for.